# conflicting conformance to protocol - best practices

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a code (swift 4.2.1, xcode 10.1) which gives a "conflicting conformance" compilation error.

How should it be re-written, what are the best practices for doing such a thing?

The code should support filtering of arrays of strings or complex objects using text search ...

```
protocol FilterableByText{
    func filter<T: StringProtocol>(by text:T) -> Self
    var isEmpty:Bool {get}
}

protocol ContainsString{
    func contains<T>(_ substring: T) -> Bool where T : StringProtocol
}

extension Array: FilterableByText where Element:ContainsString{
    func filter<T: StringProtocol>(by text:T) -> Array{
        return filter{$0.contains(text)}
    }
}

extension Array: FilterableByText where Element:FilterableByText{ // conflicting conformance
    func filter<T: StringProtocol>(by text:T) -> Array{
        return map{$0.filter(by: text)}.filter{!$0.isEmpty}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of try to have separate conformances, what you can do is create separate implementations of the function you want with different constraints.

```
protocol ContainsString {
    func contains<T>(_ substring: T) -> Bool where T: StringProtocol
}

extension Collection {
    func filter<T>(by text: T) -> [Element] where T: StringProtocol, Element: ContainsString {
        return filter { $0.contains(text) }
    }

    func filter<T>(by text: T) -> [Element] where T: StringProtocol, Element: Collection, Element.Element: ContainsString {
        return filter { !$0.filter(by: text).isEmpty }
    }
}

extension String: ContainsString {}

let strings = ["hello", "world"]
strings.filter(by: "hello") // ["hello"]

let stringOfStrings = [strings, ["foo", "bar"]]
stringOfStrings.filter(by: "hello") // ["hello", "world"]
```

Comment: +1, this is interesting. Still doesn't fit my use case, I may want to update the question. I wanted some FilterableByText protocol for use in other generic protocol with 'associatedtype Model: FilterableByText' so I could compile expressions like 'newModel = model.filter(by: searchString)'. Do you have any suggestions for this usecase?
You also missed the var isEmpty definition.

Comment: My solution extends `Collection`, which already as an `isEmpty` property.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand your use case. If you update the question with a more concrete example it'll be easier to help you to model it.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler suggest, conflicting conformance is not acceptable - the behavior will be undefined, since there is no rules for resolving clashing function signatures in extensions. For the best practices, I'd say introduce more generic, but single protocol for the elements, so it doesn't make you split logic in the default extension:

Comment: Yes, obvious, but ... could you propose anything more specific?